# Fully dynamical string arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, shell, multidimensional-array

I am currently working on a very basic shell written in C. To do that, I need to be able to break down an input string into "words" so I can send it to `execvep()`. To do that, I created a function `shishell()` that expects a string of unknown lenght and that will internally maked an array of string. Since the size of the words and their quantity isn't known beforehand, the string array is fully dynamic.

The main problem I have it that this function works well for 1 or 2 "words" in a string, but as soon as I go beyond 3 "words" it starts breaking down, causing segmentation faults and double free corruptions errors.

Here is a test program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    shishell(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

int fakexec(char** e_input_arr) {
    int c = 0;
    while(*e_input_arr) {
        char* x = *e_input_arr++; c++;
        printf(" >%d - %s\n", c, x);
    }
}

int shishell(char* e_input) {
    int n = 0,
    cur_i = 0,
    cur_w = 0;
    char tmp;
    char** input = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    input[n] = malloc(sizeof(char));

    while ((tmp = e_input[cur_i]) == ' ') {
        cur_i++;
    }
    while ((tmp = e_input[cur_i]) != '\0') {
        switch (tmp) {
            case ' ':
                if (cur_i) {
                    if (e_input[cur_i-1] != ' ') {
                        n++;
                        input = realloc(input, (n+1) * sizeof(char));
                        input[n] = malloc(sizeof(char));
                    }
                }
                cur_w = 0; cur_i++;
                break;
            default:
                input[n] = realloc(input[n], sizeof(char)*cur_w+2);
                input[n][cur_w] = e_input[cur_i];
                input[n][cur_w+1] = '\0';
                cur_w++; cur_i++;
                break;
        }
        printf(">%d - '%c'\n", n, tmp);
    }
    printf("Pre execuction\n");
    fakexec(input);

    printf("Post execuction\n");

    int j;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        free(input[j]);
    free(input);
}
```

This program expects ONE string parameter.

And here are some exeample outputs :

```
% ./test test                              
>0 - 't'
>0 - 'e'
>0 - 's'
>0 - 't'
 >1 - test

% ./test "hello world" 
>0 - 'h'
>0 - 'e'
>0 - 'l'
>0 - 'l'
>0 - 'o'
>1 - ' '
>1 - 'w'
>1 - 'o'
>1 - 'r'
>1 - 'l'
>1 - 'd'
 >1 - hello
 >2 - world
```

Everything works well for those, but then :

```
% ./test "hello world foo"
>0 - 'h'
>0 - 'e'
>0 - 'l'
>0 - 'l'
>0 - 'o'
>1 - ' '
>1 - 'w'
>1 - 'o'
>1 - 'r'
>1 - 'l'
>1 - 'd'
>2 - ' '
>2 - 'f'
>2 - 'o'
>2 - 'o'
 >1 - hello
 >2 - world
 >3 - foo
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./test "hello world foo"
```

I presume the problems may be comming from my calls to `realloc`, `malloc` and `free` however, I don't really what I'm doing wrong since I'm doing the realocations as I need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fakexec` function includes `while(*e_input_arr)`.

This will only work properly if you include a null termination entry. However you don't do that so it reads off the end of the allocated space, causing a segmentation fault.

In fact, you don't allocate `input` properly. The line `char** input = malloc(sizeof(char*));` only allocates space for `input[0]`. But you increment `n` and go on to access `input[1]` etc.

Comment: I want to add that when he allocates each line, he allocates `char*` instead of allocating `char`. To do this type of function, you need to count the number of words beforehand to be able to allocate an array containing enough memory.

Comment: Good catch. Those errors could have been avoided with the `p = malloc( N * sizeof *p);` idiom.

Comment: Following @JulienFouilhé and @MattMcNabb comments I modified the source to add `input = realloc(input, sizeof(char*)*n+1);` to reallocate the `input` properly and changing the way I realocated the lines.

I really don't get the problem with `while(*e_input_arr)` since I have no problem with one or two words thought.

Comment: @Marneus68 When you browse this way, you have to make sure that you put a NULL at the end of your array, because you don't know what will be after your array in memory. If there's a NULL (like it seems to be when you have one or two words), it will work, else you risk to go into unauthorised memory areas and you will get a Segmentation fault too.

Comment: `realloc(input, sizeof(char*)*n+1);` is wrong, the `+1` needs to go with the `n`. Again you could have avoided this by using the idiom `realloc(input, (n+1) * sizeof *input)`

Comment: @JulienFouilhé that makes sense. Thanks a lot to you both. I'll correct that. Doing the proper allocations seem to prevent me from getting the weirder double free corruptions errors I had before.

Comment: @MattMcNabb `realloc(input, (n+1) * sizeof *input)` ? Shouldn't that be something like `realloc(input, (n+1) * sizeof(input))` ?

Comment: No, the size of the thing being pointed to is the size you want

Comment: @Marneus68 When you have a `char*` you want to be able to put three characters in. What will you allocate? There characters (`char`) or three pointers on characters (`char*`)? Just think about what will be contained into the pointer, not the pointer itself :)